# Android and Google end points authentication exception

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to connect the Udacity Conference central android app to my app engine application on the google cloud.

I am getting following exception

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException" Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: INVALID_AUDIENCE"

Things I have tried:

1. Generate "WebClient ID" and "Android Client ID" in the App Engine Credentials page. Use the Web Client ID as "Android_AUDIENCE" in the app engine app and "server:client_id:" in the Android app.
2. Generate my keystore and use that when creating the android client ID. Sign the jar on command line and try to install the app by copying the apk.
3. Add my keystore credentials in the build.gradle and run the app.
4. Use the "android.keystore" release key present in the application folder.
5. use the "debug.keystore" present in the /.android folder.

Tried deleting and recreating the android client id on the google cloud console with no luck. I used this [Udacity Android <-> Cloud Endpoints app configuration](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-fx04wJCbVcIFoGL8ICnebXzUNRyphnJlLepBf9dvic/pub) for connection.

```
@Api(name = "conference",
    version = "v1",
    scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email"},
    clientIds =
            {
            Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID,Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID_2, Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID
            },
    audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
    description = "API for the Conference Central Backend application.")
```

Comment: can you please post your API Annotations for your endpoints or/and your endpoint class?

Comment: will do and Thank you.

Comment: please update your question with the code and do not put the code into your comment

Comment: is ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID? Did you try ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID_2?

Comment: ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID and its set the same in the android app. I made the WEB_CLIENT_ID_2 and tried that as well. Each time I changed the ID in the android app as well to match the Web client ID. I am wondering if its something to do with the signing of the android app.

Comment: what is the value of your Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE? I am using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

Comment: Yeah. I am using the same.  In case you want to try the code is on 
Android app: 
githubhttps://github.com/SangramMohite/conference-central-android

Google app engine:
https://github.com/SangramMohite/ConferenceCentral_Java_GoogleCloud

Answer (score 0):

'INVALID_AUDIENCE' means that you either didn't [setup](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#installedapplications&android) your Android app properly in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient), or your 'Web app Client ID' and 'Android app Client ID' are not in the same Google Cloud project.

Be sure to use the correct [package name](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) for your Android application when creating your 'Android app Client ID' in the Google Cloud Console. Also make sure you properly generated the SHA1 fingerprint.

In the same Google Cloud project, you will also need to [enable any APIs](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) you wish to use with your Client IDs.